# When i try to run my python-selenium script through cmd line, i'm facing some import errors

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, pytest, allure

When i try to run my python-selenium script through cmd line, i'm facing the below import errors. I'm not sure what problem exactly i'm facing. Can someone help me with this.

```
<name>:~/git-pythonselenium$ pytest -v -m login orangehrm.pom.tests.sampletestcases.py
Traceback (most recent call last):

    return self._inner_hookexec(hook_name, methods, kwargs, firstresult)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pluggy/_callers.py", line 55, in _multicall
    gen.send(outcome)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/_pytest/helpconfig.py", line 102, in pytest_cmdline_parse
    config: Config = outcome.get_result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pluggy/_result.py", line 60, in get_result
    raise ex[1].with_traceback(ex[2])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pluggy/_callers.py", line 39, in _multicall
    res = hook_impl.function(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 1017, in pytest_cmdline_parse
    self.parse(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 1305, in parse
    self._preparse(args, addopts=addopts)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 1188, in _preparse
    self.pluginmanager.load_setuptools_entrypoints("pytest11")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pluggy/_manager.py", line 287, in load_setuptools_entrypoints
    plugin = ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 171, in load
    module = import_module(match.group('module'))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py", line 168, in exec_module
    exec(co, module.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/google/home/name/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/allure_pytest/plugin.py", line 11, in <module>
    from allure_pytest.utils import allure_label, allure_labels, allure_full_name
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py", line 168, in exec_module
    exec(co, module.__dict__)  File"/usr/local/google/home/name/.local/lib/python3.10/sitepackages/allure_pytest/utils.py", line 8, in <module>
    from allure_commons.utils import format_exception, format_traceback, escape_non_unicode_symbols

ImportError: cannot import name 'escape_non_unicode_symbols' from 'allure_commons.utils' (/usr/local/google/home/name/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/allure_commons/utils.py)
```

Comment: You have some plugin for allure that expects *older* allure ..  escape_non_unicode_symbols has been removed and thus, you get import failure. Updated allure & what ever plugins you have.

Comment: Thanks a lot @rasjani this issue happened due to incompatible allure versions of 2.13.0. Post downgrading the versions to 2.12.0 this worked for me.